# Python - Return a new list of dictionaries whiteout certain keys and their values

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, filtering

**Context**: I need to return certain keys AND their values which are present in every dictionary of a list

**The problem** : I just can't get it right, be it via iteration, filter or list logic...

Here is an example of a list that needs to be filtered:

```
[{
"id": "id1",
"date": "2021-01-05 03:05:06",
"prochain_joueur": "joueur1",
"joueurs": ["joueur1", "joueur2"],
"state": ["pio1","pio2"],
"gagnant": "Jorje"
}, 
{...},
{
"id": "id23",
"date": "2021-01-05 03:05:06",
"prochain_joueur": "joueur2",
"joueurs": ["joueur1", "joueur2"],
"state": ["pio1","pio2"],
"gagnant": "Castillo"
}]
```

And here is what needs to be returned:

```
[{
    "id": "80a0a0d2-059d-4539-9d53-78b3f6045943",
    "date": "2021-01-23 14:23:59",
    "joueurs": ["jowic42", "robot-1"],
    "gagnant": "jowic42"
},
{...},
{
    "id": "80a0a0d2-059d-4539-9d53-78b3f6045943",
    "date": "2021-02-23 14:23:59",
    "joueurs": ["jowic42", "robot-1"],
    "gagnant": "jowic42"
}]
```

I *simply* need to return the same list witouth the keys "prochain_joueur" and "state" and I just can't figure it out. Note that originally, the list is in Json, I need to return the last 20 entries and it needs to be returned in Json but, I actually know how to do that part!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it using this:

```
for dict_iter in list_dict:
    for key in keys_to_delete:
        if key in dict_iter.keys():
            del dict_iter[key]
```

`list_dict` is your list of dictionaries, `keys_to_delete`is a list of the keys you want out e.g. `["prochain_joueur", "state"]`

Answer (score 1):

You can make a list of the keys you don't want and then use a dict comprehension inside a list comprehension to filter them out. Given your original list as `l`:

```
unwanted = ["prochain_joueur" , "state"]
filtered = [{k:v for k, v in d.items() if k not in unwanted} for d in l]
```

Which will give you:

```
[{'id': 'id1',
  'date': '2021-01-05 03:05:06',
  'joueurs': ['joueur1', 'joueur2'],
  'gagnant': 'Jorje'},
 {'id': 'id23',
  'date': '2021-01-05 03:05:06',
  'joueurs': ['joueur1', 'joueur2'],
  'gagnant': 'Castillo'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

given:
**list_of_keys** = list containing all keys to be copied
**list_of_dicts** = list of dictionaroes to search

```
def return_keys(list_of_keys, list_of_dicts):
    rslt = []
    for dct in list_of_dicts:
        td = {}
        for k in list_of_keys:
            if k in dct.keys():
                td[k] = dct[k]
        rslt.append(td)
    return rslt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach with `pandas`. You load your list of dictionaries in a `pandas.DataFrame`; the keys become your columns and the rows become your values. If a key does not exist in one of your dictionaries, the corresponding value in that row will be `nan`. So, you can delete all columns that have at least one `nan` value.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(your_list)
df.dropna(axis=1, inplace=True) # Delete columns with nan

>>> df.columns
Index(['id', 'date', 'joueurs', 'gagnant'], dtype='object')
```

And then convert your dataframe back to a list of dictionaries:

```
new_list = df.to_dict('records')
```